# setting scope to null blocks 2 way binding angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have created a directive and I believe that two-way bind is being broken when I set a bound scope variable (textStyleOriginal) to `null`. What is a good way to resolve this issue?

```
.directive('textStylePalette', function($log, toastr, _){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'app/palettes/text/text-style-palette.html',
            scope: {
                textStyleOriginal: '=textStyle'
            },
            link: textPaletteLinkFn
        };

        function textPaletteLinkFn(scope, elem, attr) {
            scope._ = _;
            scope.textStyle = null;

            // Used when closing the palette
            scope.deselectStyle = function() {
                // I BELIEVE THE PROBLEM IS THE NEXT LINE
                scope.textStyleOriginal = null;
                scope.textStyle = null;
            };

   ...
            // THIS WATCH STOPS WORKING.
            scope.$watch('textStyleOriginal', function(newVal, oldVal){
                $log.debug('n: ' + newVal + '|o: ' + oldVal );
                debugger;
                if (newVal && newVal !== oldVal) {
                    ...
                }
            });
}
```

The html where the binding is initially connected is as follows:

```
<text-style-palette ng-show="selectedStyle !== null" text-style="selectedStyle">
</text-style-palette>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few minutes after I asked the question I tried something that seemed to work. Leaving this question up to document my answer:

It was basically the simple, 'always make passed scope variables as part of an object'.

I made some changes so that the external selectedStyle that was feeding the directives was part of an object. here's the code

```
<cm-text-style-palette ng-show="selections.selectedStyle !== null" text-style="selections.selectedStyle">
</cm-text-style-palette>
```

Notice that it's **selections**.selectedStyle not just selectedStyle.

The issue has to do with how variable pointing works. For more details this video might help: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot#/tab-transcript

Best of luck with your projects!

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what's the problem.

Since you have an isolated scope, you'll have the `textStyleOriginal` set from the parent scope. It means that if you override it with the value `null`, then you'll loose the reference to the original object.
E.g. even when you modify your `textStyleOriginal` in your parent scope, it won't take any effect in your directive, since you lost the reference to it already.

Comment: Thanks @limisti. You're right it was that. Luckily I quickly found a way to resolve it soon after I posted. Thanks!

Comment: please accept my answer then :) I'm glad to help you.